# Process Scala Option type with higher-order functions

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions, idioms, scala-option

There is a class

```
class MyType {
  def status(): String = "Connected" // demo implementation
}
```

I have a `val x: Option[Option[MyType]]`. I need to process this value like the following:

```
x match {
  case None => "Error1"
  case Some(None) => "Error2"
  case Some(Some(t)) => t.status
}
```

I would like to rewrite the same code with higher order functions as it described in Tom Morris [post](https://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/). What is the correct way to code it?

---

There are some words about the motivation to ask the question. Official documentation [says](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html):

> The most idiomatic way to use an `scala.Option` instance is to treat it as a collection or monad and use `map`,`flatMap`, `filter`, or `foreach` <...>
>   A less-idiomatic way to use `scala.Option` values is via pattern matching

I am not quite sure I realize what *"idiomatic"* means exactly, but it sounds like *"good"* for me.

Comment: Note that the last `match` should be `case Some(Some(t)) => t.status`

Comment: Just sharing my two cents, if you follow @Tim advice, I would go with **pattern matching** instead of with **higher-order functions**. IMHO, it is more readable.

Comment: @Tim - Thank you. I'll fix

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - Thank you. I expanded the question with motivation to rewrite **pattern matching** code

Comment: @Loom while the phrase about the use of `Option` as a **Monad** being more idiomatic _(meaning more common / standard / good)_ is true. It also depends on the context. That, phrase refers more when you are composing multiple options with multiple functions. However, in your case, that you only want to get the result, I find **pattern matching** easier to read. - However, I may add that having an `Option[Option[X]]` is usually strange, maybe it would have been a more idiomatic way to get the same end result. I am thinking that maybe you should have used `Either`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
x.fold("Error1")(_.fold("Error2")(_.status()))
```

Answer (score 0):

`map`-way:

```
x.map(_.map(_.status).getOrElse("Error2")).getOrElse("Error1")
```